# How can I find a source function call by looking at an executable warning message?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am getting an error when I run the executable:

```
(a.out:6815): GooCanvas-CRITICAL **: goo_canvas_item_get_parent: assertion `GOO_IS_CANVAS_ITEM (item)' failed
```

I want to find out which function call is leading to this warning (since I am not calling the above function), I tried running with gdb but didn't show me the source line? I have the `-g` included when I compile. Thanks.

Comment: You have to compile with `-g` in order to get debugging information embedded into the executable file. Without it the debugger (and other source level tools) would not be able to find out the line of code given its address.

Comment: @HristoIliev I am putting the -g, how do find in gdh what `a.out: 2815` points to?

Comment: I don't see any 2815, but I think 6815 is probably just a PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `G_DEBUG=fatal_criticals` to your environment. This way, your program will abort() when a critical error occurs, so your gdb can point you where the assertion fails.

That, or adding a breakpoint to the `g_critical` function.